# Chrome auto scrolling page when content adds via js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a page with a lot of column flow content. On the page bottom there is "add" button, that adds some new content to the bottom.
When i click it Chrome scrolls the page down with added content.

https://jsfiddle.net/gydn7ptk/4/show - jsfiddle. When i scroll down and click "add" i can see "scrolled" in console.

How does it works? Why Chrome automatically scrolls down the page? Because i want to stay on the same `scrollTop` position after update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Chrome 84, the scroll anchoring selection was updated (see [Chrome commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/537603bf2f2ab1bea740bbb4137a774be76aeab5)).

To avoid the scroll, you have to remove the focus on your clicked element.

In your exemple, you need to add `e.target.blur();` on your click function.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.update', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.blur();
      for (var i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
          $('.data').append('<div><article>data</article></div>')
      }
  })
  document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {console.log('scrolled')});
```

Comment: This is so useful! Thank you!